# Retorno da função ajax com resultado de uma busca sql

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

estou fazendo uma seção no meu site, na qual há um campo `select`. Quando seleciono algo nesse `select`, eu quero realizar uma busca no BD, retornando as informações sobre aquele item selecionado para usar essas informações em outras partes do site.

Eu pensei em fazer isso utilizando **jquery** e **ajax**. Eu consigo realizar a busca, mas estou tendo problemas em pegar o retorno da busca.

Ajax:

```
 $('#sedes').on('change', function() {
            var idLoja = this.value;
            alert(idLoja);
            $.ajax({
                url: "carregarInfo.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    id: idLoja
                },
                cache: false,
                processData:true,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);   
                }
            });
        });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('conexao.php');


$idLoja = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM lojas WHERE idLoja = '$idLoja'";

$result = $conexao->query($sql) OR trigger_error($conexao->error."[$sql]");
$s = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


echo $s;
```

Como posso fazer isso da maneira certa?

Ou existe uma maneira melhor para fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Está faltando você informar como esse ajax vai trabalhar, como dados em JSON, HTML ou TEXT.

Comment: O alert aparece? Dá algum erro na consola? o que dá `var_dump($s);`?

Comment: Tem outra, o echo não imprimi um array sem você informar qual o index, você tem que tratar a saída dos dados.

Comment: o var_dump imprime o array encontrado. O alert do success dá um erro de conversão de array para string.

Comment: Oi Romario, e qual seria o certo usar?

Comment: Romário, assim você não vai pra copa de novo, hein!

Comment: Ok, então faz `echo json_encode($r);` e no AJAX junta `dataType :'json',` no objeto de configuração. Funciona?

Comment: Exatamente desse jeito que o Sérgio fez é a melhor opção a se usar!

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, funcionou com o JSON. Não conhecia ele. Vai ajudar muito!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### jSON

No retorno do **PHP**, coloque:

`echo json_encode($s);`

No **JS** coloque:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "carregarInfo.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
```

O importante no código JS acima é o `dataType: 'json'`.

Faça um `console.log(data)` e veja o que retorna.

É só fazer `data.nome_do_campo_na_tabela`. Esse `nome_do_campo_na_tabela` é o nome do campo que vem do `array` convertido em **json** no **PHP**, que é o nome do campo na tabela.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou certinho!